# App Services Web App SSO integration and Get Email Name before redirect URL

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-appservice

I Deployed my node.js application to Azure App Service, By using Authentication i Enabled Azure Active Directory in App Service app(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad).

My application will now use the Azure directory login and successfully redirects to the (mydoman.azurewebsites.net). The default redirect URI is confiured as /.auth/login/aad/callback.

Everyhting Work fine till here. But the next thing is I want to get emailID of the logged User and do the action my application. **I dont know form redirection URL how can i get the email ID to use in my application**

I m attaching the webbrowser console in netwrok tab. In between callback service and dashboard i want top ass email and render dashboard with user data on my application.

For the callback redirect  /.auth/login/aad/callback. [image]URI , I m getting code and access Token also.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the email ID you mean is also the *user principal name* of the logged user.
So if you want to get it, you just need to access the `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME` request header.

For more details, see [Access user claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#access-user-claims).

Comment: Hey Joy Wang, thanks for the input, I followed the appraoch using nodejs passport to get the token and profile information

Comment: @prudviraju Did you use `req.user` to get the user information? https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad#422-use-passportauthenticate-to-protect-resources-or-apis